# AWS PHP connection

Tags: php, aws-cli, amazon-lightsail

I have a Lighsail LAMP stack. I’ve uploaded my PHP file which is a simple contact us page.

I’ve created a database in phpmyadmin. I’d like to know:
What will be the database username?
What will be the database password?

Looking forward for your support.

Answer (score 0):

- Database username: root.
- Database password: The same as the [application password](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/infrastructure/lamp/get-started/first-steps/).

Comment: thanks @ZakariaChabihi

However when I visit the website the page doesn't show up. I've kept host as: localhost

Answer (score 0):

The password is contained in the file /home/bitnami/bitnami_application_password. As noted above the the username is root.

I have a tutorial up at https://lightsailworkshop.com that will walk you through configuring a LAMP application on Lightsail, that might be helpful